# Difference of KL Divergences

Tags: information-theory, mutual-information

I am interested in the difference of KL divergences
\begin{align}
KL&(p(x)||q(x))-KL(p(x|y)||q(x|y)) = \\ &\int p(x)\log\dfrac{p(x)}{q(x)}dx-\int p(y)\int p(x|y)\log\dfrac{p(x|y)}{q(x|y)}dxdy
\end{align}
I want to make this difference equal to zero. I can't just minimize this quantity as the difference of KL's can be negative. $p(x|y)$ is intractable so I can not directly compute the conditional KL divergence term. Is there any way that I can choose a $q(x|y)$ to know what the conditional KL evaluates to without needing to compute the KL directly? Or is there some theorems/resources that explore properties of the differences of KL divergences that I can hopefully leverage?

Comment: Your equation is a bit confused. For example $y$ appears as a free variable on the LHS but as a bound variable on the RHS. Also there are more integral signs than $dx$s and $dy$s. But since $p(x)=\int p(x,y)\,dy$ my guess is that what you're aiming for could be $\int \int p(x,y)\log\frac{p(x)}{q(y)}dx\,dy-\int\int p(x,y)\log\frac{p(x,y)/p(y)}{q(x,y)/q(y)}dx\,dy$$=\int\int p(x,y)\left(\log\frac{q(x,y)}{q(x)q(y)}-\log\frac{p(x,y)}{p(x)p(y)}\right)dx\,dy$. Is it?

Comment: Sorry, I had included an extra integral for the marginal KL divergence, I have edited that. The notation of the KL I am using does not mean that $y$ is a free variable, it should taken in expectation. However, the final result you have written is correct, that is an equivalent way of writing the quantity I am interested in